# Json Response parsing

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch

I got json reponse in the following way...i have tried to parse in many ways all went ruin.

dic:

```
(

        {
        events =         {
            id = 1;
            name = "Event One";
        };
    },

        {
        events =         {
            id = 2;
            name = "Test 2";
        };
    },
        {
        events =         {
            id = 12;
            name = "vivek 11";
        };
    },  
)

NSDictionary *jsonDictionaryResponse = [response JSONValue];

NSString *name=[[[jsonDictionaryResponse objectForKey:@"events"]objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"name"];
```

json response:

> Login response :[{"events":{"id":"1","name":" Event
>   One"}},{"events":{"id":"2","name":"Test
>   2"}},{"events":{"id":"12","name":"vivek
>   11"}},{"events":{"id":"13","name":"Baby's Day
>   out"}},{"events":{"id":"15","name":"Childrens
>   Day"}},{"events":{"id":"16","name":"event
>   two"}},{"events":{"id":"17","name":"Test
>   Creattion"}},{"events":{"id":"29","name":"Susan
>   Test"}},{"events":{"id":"30","name":"Summer
>   Holidays"}},{"events":{"id":"38","name":"Event
>   7"}},{"events":{"id":"69","name":"vivek event for
>   tests"}},{"events":{"id":"102","name":"chinees food mela"}}]

Comment: Can you add the code that you used to try and parse this

Comment: thats not json. first you have to cut "dic:(" and the last",)". Then you have to replace all "=" with ":". If you did that, try it again.

Comment: first check in my answer it is not in JSON format and another thing u better make a tree of the arrays and dictionaries. then you will come to know whats the problme is

Comment: json response..which i got added

Comment: The JSON response is an *array* (of dictionaries) and not a *dictionary*. Have a look at http://json.org for the meaning of `[ ... ]` and `{ ... }`. There are also dozens of similar Q&A here on SO.

Comment: Please find my updated answer below nd let me know if it is not working

Comment: this is parsed already

Answer (score 1):

first transform your response string to NSData. then try this:

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *jSONArray  = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
for (NSDictionary *dict in jSONArray) {
    NSDictionary *event = [dict objectForKey=@"events"];
    NSString *name = [event objectForKey:@"name"];
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that result coming as JSON. it is not aDictionary check it 
[here](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)

PLease find the code here

```
NSArray *jsonArrayResponse = [response JSONValue];
NSDictionary *firstDic = [jsonArrayResponse objectAtIndex:0];
NSDictionary *secondDic = [firstDic objectForKey:@"events"];
NSLog(@"The values in the events dictioanry is %@ ",[secondDic allValues]);
NSString *stringNAme = [secondDic objectForKey:@"id"];
```

Comment: Response is json i have checke,later i take that into jsonDictionaryResponse.

Comment: that is not a dictionary 
that is array first please find the edited answer above

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to understand a JSON object in Objective-C is to understand how it breaks things up into Arrays and Dictionaries.  Every time you see a "[" think Array.  Every time you see a "{" think Dictionary.

An Array can have Dictionary or other Array objects as part of the collection and a Dictionary can have Array or more Dictionary objects which can contain more Arrays or Dictionaries.

If you remember that "[ ]" means Array and "{ }" means Dictionary, you will know JSON in Objective-C.